# Java 8 Streams Grouping by an Optional Attribute

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type, collectors

I am trying to groupby a computed value from an attribute. The computed value is optional - to be a little more clear, his is a simplified example:

```
class Foo: 
   int id;
   Group group;
   .. some other stuff

class Group: 
   String groupId;
   ... (some other stuff)

class SomeName:
   String someAttribute;

class Converter:
   public Optional<SomeName> getSomenameFromGroup(Group)
```

I cannot change the methods in Converter since it doesn't belong to me.

I have a list of Foo, that I want to filter by SomeName's "someAttribute".

For example, I have something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> fooBySomeName = 
  fooList.stream().collect(Collectors
    .groupingBy(foo -> {
        Optional<SomeName> name = 
           converter.getSomenameFromGroup(foo.getGroup.getGroupId());
        return name.isPresent() ? name.get().someAttribute() : "";
    }));
```

But the thing is, I don't want anything in my map if the name isn't present in the groupingBy statement. I had something like this:

```
fooBySomeNames.remove("")
```

which I think can remove anything from the map which was grouped by that key, but is there a cleaner or more correct way to do this in the groupingBy statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove entries with a filter as follows.

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> fooBySomeName = fooList.stream()
    .filter(foo -> fooToSomeAttribute(foo).isPresent())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(foo -> fooToSomeAttribute(foo).get()));

private static Optional<String> fooToSomeAttribute(Foo foo)
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(foo)
        .map(Foo::getGroup)
        .flatMap(new Converter()::getSomenameFromGroup)
        .map(SomeName::getSomeAttribute);
}
```

Or, with a pair object, you can avoid double computation of someAttribute for every Foo:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> fooBySomeName = fooList.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(FooAndSomeAttribute::new)
    .filter(pair -> pair.getSomeAttribute().isPresent())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        pair -> pair.getSomeAttribute().get(),
        Collectors.mapping(
            FooAndSomeAttribute::getFoo, 
            Collectors.toList())));

private static class FooAndSomeAttribute
{
    private final Foo foo;
    private final Optional<String> someAttribute;

    public FooAndSomeAttribute(Foo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.someAttribute = Optional.ofNullable(foo)
            .map(Foo::getGroup)
            .flatMap(new Converter()::getSomenameFromGroup)
            .map(SomeName::getSomeAttribute);
    }

    public Foo getFoo() 
    {
        return foo;
    }

    public Optional<String> getSomeAttribute() 
    {
        return someAttribute;
    }
}
```